# Area code is already set: while set:upgrade command in RecurringData.php magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.0, recurring

> Hi all, i am facing this error while setup:upgrade command  in
>   RecurringData.php file magento 2.
>
> I tried all code mentioned in below link
>
> [Git hub link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5285)
>
> Please guide me,if you have any idea related this topic
>
> Please check below bin\magento file

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

echo "\n";
if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
    echo 'bin/magento must be run as a CLI application';
    exit(1);
}

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Autoload error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}
try {
    $handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
    set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);
    $application = new Magento\Framework\Console\Cli('Magento CLI');
    $application->run();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    while ($e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
        echo "\n\n";
        $e = $e->getPrevious();
    }
    exit(Magento\Framework\Console\Cli::RETURN_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: please attach screen shot of error

Comment: @Rk, sorry i am not able to share the screenshots due to some company policies        At the last line: Running data recurring...Area code is already set

Comment: i think this error for custom module

Comment: when you setup upgrade check which module is not update means which module throw this error

Comment: @RkRathod this error not coming due to any custom module because i am using 3 RecurringData.php in 3 custom module and after debugging i found  this error executing randomly in these 3 modules one by one or sometimes in 2 modules also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know this is the rightway or not but it's solution is in

> /var/www/html/magento231(your magento root directory)/bin/magento

open this file

add after

```
 <?php
```

below line

**echo "\n";**

and your error will go away

Comment: @Rutvi, even still error is exists

Comment: @HiteshBalpande add your bin/magento file code in question

Comment: please check my updated question, thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen if extension console scripts are written in a certain way that was fine under previous versions. But that means that you've got to disable and reenable console scripts from third party modules one by one removing entry from di.xml and compiling until you find the culprit. It's likely there is one which is setting area code in the constructor instead of part of the execution method. Last time this happened to me it took a while to find the culprit. But also removing from constructor means something in the script itself will break and potentially it's a  bit of a rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

## File: vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php

in this function `public function setAreaCode($code)`

```
try {
        $appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
    } catch (MagentoFrameworkExceptionLocalizedException $e) {
        // intentionally left empty
    }
    parent::__construct($name);
```

you can follow this link, you will get solution : [click here](https://alanstorm.com/magento-2-more-on-setting-area-codes/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/167465)

Comment: okay thanks will take care